# How to read a file from src/instrumentTest/resources directory in Android?

Tags: android, testing, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android application using the new standard gradle layout:

```
  src/main/java
  src/main/resources
  src/instrumentTest/java
  src/instrumentTest/resources
```

I have a unit test in `src/instrumentTest/java/com/example/MyUnitTest.java` that reads a file located in  `src/instrumentTest/resources/testfile.json`

- First question: Is it the right place for placing the testing files?
- Second question: How can I read that file in a String?

I have tried these two ways for reading the file in the unit test with no success (it cannot find the file):

```
String myJson = new Scanner(new File("testfile.json"),"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();

String myJson = new Scanner(new File("resources/testfile.json"),"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the assets folder of the build type your are testing. If you are testing the debug type (which is the default one):

```
src/debug/res/assets
```

And then you access those files with

```
InputStream raw = context.getAssets().open("filename.ext");
String myJson = new Scanner(raw).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

The trick of using the *debug* build type prevent your testing resources to be packed in the final apk.

Comment: where do you get the context from in the unit-test function?

Comment: we are talking about instrumentation tests