# How to configure testing assets in Android Studio/Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

For my tests, I want to use some assets which are only used for testing, e.g. a json file called `bundle1.json`. I moved this file in the in the folder `src/androidTest/assets`:

[image]

However, when I try to load the file `bundle1.json`:

`getContext().getResources().getAssets().open("bundle1.json");`

I get a `FileNotFoundException`. Do I have to change my build.gradle?

Comment: This could be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833006/how-to-read-a-file-from-src-instrumenttest-resources-directory-in-android/21909245#21909245

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use `InstrumentationTestCase`, but `ApplicationTestCase`

Comment: It should work in the same way.

Comment: Try `getSystemContext()` instead of `getContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the class loader:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("assets/bundle1.json");
```