# Mock FileInputStream for AndroidInstrumentation test

Tags: android, mockito, inputstream, fileinputstream

I want to read from a file in my Instrumentation test:

```
public class MyTest extends AndroidTestCase {

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        ...
    }
}
```

I tried following ways but non of them was successful:
`InputStream inputStream = getContext().getAssets().open("myFile");` and `File myFile = new File("src/androidTest/myFile");`

I gave a try to

```
Resources res = getContext().getResources();
InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.testfile)
```

which is suggested in [How to read a file from src/instrumentTest/resources directory in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833006/how-to-read-a-file-from-src-instrumenttest-resources-directory-in-android), but I do not have access to R.

Do you know how can I do it?

I want to mock a `FileInputStream`.

***Addenda :***

I found a workaround to get a inputStream:

```
InputStream inputStream = getInstrumentation()
                .getContext()
                .getResources()
                .openRawResource(com.mypackage.instrumenttest.
                        R.raw.sifo_cookie_key_json);
```

The case is I need to extend `InstrumentationTestCase` and not `AndroidTestCase` to have access to `R`

But what I need is a `fileInputStream`, and not inputStream since I need to have following mocking return:

```
when(mockContext.openFileInput(FILE_NAME)).thenReturn(fileInputStream);
```

And openFileInput :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String) returns fileInputStream

I made a workaround to convert InputStream to fileInputStream:

```
final File file = File.createTempFile("file", ".txt");
convertStreamToFile(inputStream, file);

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

But it is not a nice solution, and I wonder if I can get `FileInputStream` instead of `InputStream`?

Comment: Are you trying to read a real file, or create a mock file?

Comment: A real file which I put in raw folder under resources.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to edit your question and tags to remove "mock". Unless you want a fake object with no real data (or limited real data), mocks and mocking frameworks like Mockito are irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Actually, then, does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9898634/1426891) solve your problem?

Comment: I will look into it and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jeff, I tried both solution in the link but for some reason both failed, but I found another solution which I have added in the Addenda.

Comment: Have you tried Robolectric? I test resources all the time without mocking anything.

Comment: @Jeff, I appreciate if you look at addenda and let me know if you have any suggestion.

Comment: Yes I did, but I want to test cookieManager and I face with another issue in Robolectric framework which I reported https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1918, and wait for their answer. It is 10 days waiting now :)