# Accessing a file in InstrumentationTest class

Tags: android, instrumentation

How can I get access to a file for an Instrumentation test without using the `AssetManager` or a `ClassLoader`.

I'm doing an integration test on my MediaPlayerFragment which takes in a String representing the filename. I don't want to     `getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources().getAssets().open(testFile);`

or

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
```

because my MediaPlayerFragment takes a filename and makes the `FileInputStream` itself.

My problem is I keep getting:

```
FileNotFoundException SC-00.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).
```

My test is in:

```
src/androidTest/java/com.olfybsppa.inglesaventurero.tests/nonUIFragments/MediaPlayerFragment1Test
```

My asset is in:  `src/androidTest/assets/SC-00.mp3`

I've tried giving the filename as 'assets/SC-00.mp3' and 'androidTest/assets/SC-00.mp3'- no luck.

my sourceSets is

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/start', 'src/main/java/adapters', 'src/main/java/pagers']
  }
}
```

but that doesn't  work.

I've also tried adding

```
androidTest {
  java.srcDir 'src/androidTest/assets'
}
```

to my source sets and that doesn't work.

SIMPLIFICATION 1.

This is a simplified version of my test class. I keep getting a FileNotFoundException. I'm trying to figure out what String filename should be?

```
public class MediaPlayerFragment1Test
                extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<DefaultActivity> {

  private DefaultActivity mActivity;
  private Instrumentation mInstrumentation;
  private String filename = "file:///androidTest/assets/SC-00.mp3";
  public static String MEDIA_PLAYER_TAG = "MEDIA PLAYER TAG";

  public MediaPlayerFragment1Test() {
    super(DefaultActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = getActivity();
  }

  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }


  @SmallTest
  public void testFileIsAccessible() {
    try {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      assertTrue(e instanceof FileNotFoundException);
      assertTrue(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open an `InputStream` on an asset normally, because assets are packaged inside your apk. `AssetManager.open` provides a way to work around this, but you said you don't want to do that.

If you need a file path which can be opened with a `FileInputStream`, you could take your asset, copy it to a temporary File and then pass the path of the temp file into your method.

```
File temp = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
InputStream in = assetManager.open("asset");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
  out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
String filePath = temp.getPath();
```

Rember to delete the temp file when you are done.

Comment: Well, that worked for me. I also added temp.deleteOnExit(); to my code.

Comment: So the answer was filename = "assets/SC-00.mp"; and I do have androidTest {java.srcDir 'src/androidTest/assets'} in my gradle file.

Comment: Note that `deleteOnExit` is not guaranteed to delete the file on android. As this file is in a cache directory which is cleared on restart anyway it doesn't really matter. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29

Answer (score 0):

One possible way of doing it is to store the file on the `ExternalStorageDirectory`, and access it like:

```
String directory = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = directory + File.separator + "some_file.txt";

try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        // Do something with the reader.
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            fail();
    }
```

---

**EDIT:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503114/android-test-project-reading-assets-file-to-test-plain-java-object) might be related.

**Second edit:** From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833006/how-to-read-a-file-from-src-instrumenttest-resources-directory-in-android), it seems you have to place your file in the build type you're testing. If it's the debug one, try:

```
src/debug/res/assets
```

Comment: putting the file in external storage is not good testing methodology because it's not easily reproducible. I tried putting it in src/debug/res/assets and also src/debug/assets and no luck. I tried filename="res/assets/SC-00.mp3", filename="assets/SC-00.mp3", filename="SC-00.mp3", each time I got the 'name of filepath': open failed: ENOENT.